# Android can not change default time out value with KSOAP library

Tags: android

i am using KSOAP 2.5.7 to accesss my web service.
But the call to web url got time out after  particular seconds .
i want to change the default time out value.but it is not changing even if i set the time out value in the call new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_URL,20000)

Comment: Try this jar,ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.2-jar-with-dependencies_timeout1.jar

Comment: And the code to set time out as httpTransport.setTimeout(MaxDurations);